# Чому зараз почали писати Гоґвортс, а не Хогвартс?

Tags: переклад, правопис, орфографія

Це якісь нові правила транслітераціі?

З [української] [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D2%91%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%81): *Гоґвортс* (англ. *Hogwarts*)

Тепер *h* — це *г*, а *g* — це *ґ*?

Тепер у нас *ґенератори*, *меґавати*, *ґаражі*, *геллоу*?

UPD: Якщо послухати оригінал — на Ютьюбі [*Welcome to Hogwarts [Harry Potter] Visit the Castle*](//youtu.be/Jwe1ASpSmRk?t=12) — абсолютно чітко чутно *Хогвартс*, а ніякий не *Гоґвортс*.

Comment: закрив питання, бо уже підіймалося безліч разів на сайті. транслітерація - це не те, як ми чуємо, ти транслітерація - це усталені зручні правила передачі іншомовних слів на письмі. чому? тому що одна людина чує так, а інша - інакше. а правила для всіх.

Comment: і писати так почали не зараз, а з 2002 року, коли видали Гаррі Поттера українською у видавництві абабагаламага.

Comment: По-перше, питання зовсім не про те, якою мовою я його читав - тому ваша репліка абсолютно недоречна. По-друге, серйозно, "одна так, друга так" - хоч хтось чує там *Гогвардс*, камон?

Comment: @P.Vowk Сподівався, хоч тут адекватну відповідь отримати. "Дякую" за дискредитацію і цього дежерела інформаціі. Добре, хоч Саша адекватно відповів.

Comment: Надав [відповѣдь](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/7168/585) там.

Comment: Ну, ситуація така, що в нас зараз не дуже багато активних учасників. Тому маємо два наслідки: (1) нам не вистачає рук, щоб глибоко пірнати в кожне питання; (2) курс задається активними учасниками, зараз він такий який є, але нові активні учасники можуть його змінити. Приєднуйтеся, якщо теж вважаєте, що нам варто бути уважнішими/лагіднішими до відвідувачів :).

Comment: @Bocchi Дякую, як раз дивлюсь відповіді на те питання

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko на нашому сайті вже не раз відбувалося обговорення на тему "чітко чую так", "чітко чую сяк". Це ніяк не впливає на транслітерацію. Так, я там чую Гоґвартс, і я досліджував це питання, ще багато людей чує дуже по-різному, для того й потрібні фонетичні дослідження + транслітерація як зручний інструмент із чіткими правилами, а не хто як почув.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko видалив частину про те, якою мовою ви то читали. Це була помилка з мого боку. Решта моїх арґументів лишається.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Про [h]

[[h] — це **глухий гортанний** фрикативний](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). В українській мові цього звука нема, а найближчі звуки, що є в українській мові, такі:

- Звук від літери *г*: є різні погляди щодо його природи, але здебільшого вважають, що це [**дзвінкий** гортанний фрикативний (позначається [ɦ])](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). Тобто спосіб творення той самий (гортанний), але дзвінкість/глухість інша (дзвінкий, а не глухий).
- Звук від літери *х*: [глухий **велярний** фрикативний (позначається [x])](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). Тобто спосіб творення інший (велярний, а не гортанний), але дзвінкість/глухість та сама (глухий).

Тобто досконалості нема. Одне з двох: або ми поступаємося способом творення і зберігаємо дзвінкість/глухість (передаючи [h] як *х*), або ми поступаємося дзвінкістю/глухістю і зберігаємо спосіб творення (передаючи [h] як *г*). Що краще?

На мій суб'єктивний погляд сучасної людини, [h] справді схожіше до *х* [x], ніж до *г* [ɦ].

Але традиція передавати [h] як *г* склалася дуже давно. (Причому, як не дивно, не тільки в українській мові, а й у російській.) Через що маємо *гандбол* (*handball*), *гербарій* (*herbarium*), *гіпотеза* (*hypothesis*), *Гарвард* (*Harward*), *Гаррі* (*Harry*), *Гітлер* (*Hitler*) тощо. А спосіб передавати [h] як *х* [x] — навпаки, порівняно новий. (І, можливо, він спочатку з'явився в російській, бо звучання *г* там змінилося з фрикативного на проривне, тобто передання [h] через *г* там утратило всяку рацію. Але це неточно.)

Правопис теж каже, що [h] «здебільшого» передається через *г* (лишаючи *х* лише для «окремих» винятків). І не лише найновіший (2019), а й усі попередні теж.

**Отже коротко про [h]:**

- **історично передавали здебільшого як *г*** (можна дискутувати про доречність чи недоречність продовження цієї традиції в сучасному світі, але це точно не якась нова зміна);
- **чинний правопис також радить передавати здебільшого як *г***.

#### Про [ɡ]

[[ɡ] (дзвінкий велярний проривний)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) — це якраз звук від *ґ*, не від *г*. (І мені дивно чути, що в слові *Hogwarts* Ви чуєте там *г*, а не *ґ*. Хіба що в окремих випадках при дуже швидкій вимові. А [тут](https://youtu.be/DIPSy8lD1Wc?t=13)? А [в слові *hog*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hog#Pronunciation)?)

Водночас сучасний правопис (2019) рекомендує передавати [ɡ] через *г* (зазначаючи *ґ* лише як альтернативний варіант і лише для прізвищ та імен людей). Але слід зазначити:

1. Історичний контекст:

   - [«Український правопис з словничком»](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=11911) Івана Огієнка (1925):

     > § 144. Звук *g* в чужих словах на письмі передають:
     >
     > а. На Великій Україні, зберігаючи власну традицію, через *г*: *г*азета, *г*ама, *г*енерал, *г*еографія, *г*імназія.
     >
     > б. В Галичині через *ґ*: *ґ*азета, *ґ*ама, *ґ*енерал, *ґ*еографія, *г*і*ґ*ієна.

     Нині майже ніхто не спирається на правопис Огієнка, але просто було цікаво зазирнути.
   - [«Харківський» правопис](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) (1928):

     > § 55… Щождо чужого g, то в новіших запозиченнях його треба передавати через **ґ**, у запозиченнях же засвоєних давніше, особливо з грецької мови, віддаємо нашим **г** (порівн. § 54): *Ан**г**лія*, ***г**аз*, ***г**азе́та*, ***г**а́ма*, ***г**е**г**емо́нія*, ***г**енеало́гія* (*ло́**г**іка*…), ***г**енера́л*, ***г**еній*, ***г**ео**г**ра́фія* (***г**рама́тика*, *про**г**ра́ма*, ***г**рамофо́н*, *дія**г**ра́ма*, ***г**ра́фіка*, ***г**рам*, *кіло**г**ра́м*…), ***Г**ерма́нія*, ***г**і**г**іє́на*, ***г**імна́зія*, ***г**іпс*, ***г**ра́дус*, ***г**раф*, ***Г**ру́зія*, ***г**ру́па*, *дифто́н**г***, *е**г**ої́зм*, *ор**г**аніза́ція*, *педа**г**о́**г***, *Ри́**г**а*, *тра**г**е́дія*, *фі**г**у́ра* й ін., але *а**ґ**е́нт*, *а**ґ**іта́ція*, *а**ґ**роном*, *Ара**ґ**о́нія*, *бра́внін**ґ***, *Брю́**ґґ**е*, *Гамбур**ґ***, *Ге**ґ**ель*, *гіда́ль**ґ**о*, *гу**ґ**ено́ти*, _Гю**ґ**о́, ***ґ**арантія*, ***Ґ**аро́нна*, ***ґ**ва́рдія*, ***Ґ**віне́я*, ***Ґ**е́ргард*, ***Ґ**е́те*, ***Ґ**еттін**ґ**ен*, ***ґ**ібелі́н*, ***ґ**ірля́нда*, ***ґ**ля́вберова сіль*, ***ґ**лядія́тор*, ***ґ**найс*, ***Ґ**о́льфштром*, ***Ґ**рана́да*, ***ґ**рандіо́зний*, ***Ґ**рі**ґ***, ***ґ**у́ма*, ***Ґ**устав*, *дири**ґ**е́нт*, *еле**ґ**а́нтний*, *інтелі**ґ**е́нт*, *лін**ґ**ві́ст*, *мі**ґ**ра́ція*, *Чіка́**ґ**о* і т. ін.

     Формально цей правопис зараз нечинний, але це був останній український правопис перед початком радянських репресій, і багато хто сприймає саме його як незамулений взірець. Наступний правопис, 1933 року, мав доволі ідеологічно забарвлену передмову про «шкідницьку роботу українських націоналістів» і скасував більшу частину правопису 1928 року, зокрема й велів [ɡ] передавати як *г*. Частину норм правопису 1928 повернули в післярадянські часи, але передання [ɡ] через *ґ* не повернув навіть правопис 2019. Чому так, сказати важко: можливо, недоробка, можливо, раціональне рішення.
2. Існують сучасні настанови, які рекомендують передавати [ɡ] через *ґ*, наприклад:

   - [Інструкції та кодекси усталеної практики з передачі географічних назв зарубіжних країн засобами української мови](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816063935/http://www.ukrmap.com.ua/services/kodeksi-ustalenoji-praktiki/) 2001 року від ДНВП «Картографія».
   - [Англо-українська практична транскрипція](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) в українській «Вікіпедії».

**Отже коротко про [ɡ]:**

- **передання через *ґ* — це порівняно нове й водночас забуте старе** (колись так робили, принаймні на Галичині; у радянські часи скасували — разом з усією літерою *ґ*);
- **але чинний правопис радить передавати здебільшого як *г*** (хоча існують настанови, що намагаються йти поперед нього).

#### Інше

Див. також: [«Правила вживання літери г/ґ/х при запозиченні іншомовних слів на g/h (гакер, гостинг)»](/q/347).

Comment: (Моя відповідь «пролізла», бо я почав її набирати до закриття питання. Попереднє запитання бачив, але там не було прямої відповіді на «як давно? чи нове?», вибачте. Можу спробувати перекинути в попереднє запитання з якоюсь передмовою, мовляв, відповідав не зовсім на це питання, а не схоже.)

Comment: Дякую за нормальну, розгорнуту, адекватну відповідь!

Comment: Як на мене, перекидати нікуди не треба - це актуальне питання, я б його і не закривав би. Бо перед тим як його задавати, я шукав схожі відповіді - і саме на те формулювання не наткнувся.

Comment: PS: в словi hog - дійсно, друга приголосна звучить як "ґ", але це точно "хоґ", а не "гоґ".